# Why does Grails keep asking me to 'upgrade' to a lower plugin version?

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies

I'm attempting to use Resources 1.2.RC3, but every time I compile or attempt to run I get the following prompt.  I've run a dependecy-report and it correctly reports that 1.2.RC3 has evicted 1.1.6 for those things that request 1.1.6 or higher.  Is this something to do with an RC version?  Is there any way I can get it to stop asking?

> You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [resources-1.2.RC3]. Do you want to update to [resources-1.1.6]? [y,n]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way I can get it to stop asking?

Work out which plugin is requesting 1.1.6 and exclude the transitive dependency in BuildConfig.

```
plugins {
  compile(':some-plugin:1.2.3') {
    excludes 'resources'
  }
}
```

I had the same problem and couldn't rely on the usual eviction logic to avoid the downgrade prompt, the only reliable option was the explicit exclude. If the offending plugin was installed using the deprecated `install-plugin` script then you'll have to remove the line that this added in `application.properties` and add the correct BuildConfig dependency (with the `excludes`) instead.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  My plugins were all already dependencies in BuildConfig.